# IOS app store error : Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File in ionic3?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval, info.plist

Yesterday I've submitted my app for review to the App Store Connect. Although the app is still under review, I've received an email to inform me that I have to fix an error.Here is the screenshort of the error:

[image]

I don't know how to access and modify the Info.plist.I don't even use calender,contacts,microphone,motion in my app.so why i received a email regarding above mentioned key?
Any idea?

Comment: open project in Xcode and please check `Info.plist` file. in that file, you can see all strings.

Comment: in `Info.plist` file, you can double click on message and edit your message.

Comment: @iNiravKotecha:- thanks  sir but i have used only location and camera in my app i don't even use any one key that mentioned in email?

Answer (score 3):

this is because even if you don't use those permissions but one of the third party libraries includes them in its `info.plist` , then you also have to include them and write the usage description into your `info.plist` file.
so, to do so:-
1- you can add those keys in the config file:

1. -for contacts key
   `<edit-config target="NSContactsUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
   <string>Your description here</string>
   </edit-config>`
2. -for calendar key
   `<edit-config target="NSCalendarsUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
   <string>Your description here</string>
   </edit-config>`
3. -for microphone key
   `<edit-config target="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
   <string>Your description here</string>
   </edit-config>`

2- add those keys from xcode

1. open info.plist in xcode as a source code.
2. add `<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
   <string>your description here </string>`
3. repeat for all keys.
4. save and close.

Comment: i tried above solution but not worked for me if i upload my app with ur changes app is failed again but if i add keys only ino.plist then upload but again upload above error gone

Comment: you have to add the keys only in `info.plist` or in config file not both. please tell me if it worked fine.

Comment: @yes it's worked but only info.plist file not config file